# Adding JavaScript to StenclJS Listen event

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

I want to change the background of my component when the window is scrolled down, and I tried implementing it this way but it doesnt work. Any guidance would be helpful!

```
export class NewsContainer{
     @Listen('scroll', { target: 'window' })
        handleScroll(ev) {
        var newsContainer=  document.querySelector(".newsContainer");
        newsContainer.classList.remove("transparentBackground");
        newsContainer.classList.add("darkBackground");
      }

    render(){
        return  [
          <div class="newsContainer transparentBackground">Content</div>
        ]
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
news-container.entry.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at NewsContainer.handleScroll
```

Comment: The code looks correct. If you could share more related code, maybe we could help you find the issue. Here's a working example: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Wg3mnbnQd0bZJdgYHHob?pm=1.

Comment: hey @SimonHänisch I updated my question with the error and some more details!

Comment: Well, then probably the issue is that `document.querySelector(".newsContainer")` returns `null` which means no element with that selector exists on your page. Can’t tell you why though... according to what you shared of your code it seems like it should be there, but maybe something else removes the element or class. Have you tried inspecting the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I faced from time to time is that some hooks or listener are executed **before** the elements are rendered and available in the DOM tree (the render function is called).  That can lead to a termination of the JavaScript in order to stop the application. I bet this is exactly why you get this error. So a simple if condition should be sufficient like:

```
     @Listen('scroll', { target: 'window' })
      handleScroll(ev) {
        var newsContainer=  document.querySelector(".newsContainer");
        if(newsContainer && newsContainer.classList){
         newsContainer.classList.remove("transparentBackground");
         newsContainer.classList.add("darkBackground");
        }
      }
```

I would go a step further and use references since I think it looks a bit clearer and has the charme that you are independent of classNames. and you can access the element from every method and validate a bit easier:

```
export class NewsContainer{
     private element;

     @Listen('scroll', { target: 'window' })
     handleScroll(ev) {
        if(!this.element) return;
        this.element.classList.remove("transparentBackground");
        this.element.classList.add("darkBackground");
      }

    render(){
        return  [
          <div ref={(el) => {this.element = el}} class="newsContainer transparentBackground">Content</div>
        ]
    }
}
```

You can use `this.element` which refers to your div element.